# How to export flexigrid to excel and pdf in asp

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I need to export `flexigaid` data in excel and PDF I need to know what I should do. I'm using  `ASP xml`.
Look at the following picture:

[image]

I have added the code which I am using as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(new function(){

            $("#fgrdProduct").flexigrid
            (
            {
            url: 'FlexiGridService.asmx/GetProductList',
            dataType: 'xml',
            colModel : [
            {display: 'Id', name : 'Id', width : 20, sortable : true, align: 'left'},
            {display: 'Name', name : 'Name', width : 180, sortable : true, align: 'left'},
            {display: 'Description', name : 'Description', width : 180, sortable : true, align: 'left'},
            {display: 'Unit', name : 'Unit', width : 120, sortable : true, align: 'left'},
            {display: 'Unit Price', name : 'UnitPrice', width : 130, sortable : true, align: 'left', hide: false},
            {display: 'Create Date', name : 'CreateDate', width : 80, sortable : true, align: 'left'}
            ],buttons: [{ name: ' Excel', bclass: 'add', onpress: doCommand },
                          { name: ' PDF', bclass: 'edit', onpress: doCommand },
                          { separator: true }
                          ],

            searchitems : [
            {display: 'Name', name: 'Name'},
            {display: 'Description', name : 'Description'},
            {display: 'Unit', name : 'Unit'},
            {display: 'Unit Price', name : 'UnitPrice'},
            {display: 'Create Date', name : 'CreateDate'},
            {display: 'Id', name : 'Id', isdefault: true}
            ],
            sortname: "Name",
            sortorder: "asc",
            usepager: true,
            title: 'List of Products',
            useRp: true,
            rp: 10,
            showTableToggleBtn: true,
            width: 1000,
            onSubmit: addFormData,
            height: 400
            }
            );

        //This function adds paramaters to the post of flexigrid. You can add a verification as well can 
        //return false if you don't want flexigrid to submit            
        function addFormData()
        {
        var dt = $('#sform').serializeArray();
        $("#fgrdProduct").flexOptions({params: dt});
        return true;
        }
        $('#sform').submit
        (
            function ()
            {
            $('#fgrdProduct').flexOptions({newp: 1}).flexReload();
            return false;
            }
            );  
        });function doCommand(com, grid){if (com=='Excel'){// i shd do something here! }else if (com=='PDF'){ here also} }//
    </script>
```

How can I export in PDF or Excel format file?

Comment: Excel onpress doCommand 
PDF onpress doCommand